Total variation measure
In my measure theory book, it is said that when $\mu\in M^1(X)$, where $X$ is a locally compact topological space and $M^1(X)$ is the space of signed radon measure with finite total variation on $X$, we can find a function $k\in L^1(X)$ such that $\mu = k\lvert\mu\rvert$, $\lvert \mu\rvert = \mu_1 + \mu_2$.
I tried to decompose $\mu$ as follows :
$\int_{X}fd\mu = \int_{X}fd\mu_1 - \int_{X}fd\mu_2$ but it does not help.
Have you an idea on how to prove this please ?
Thank you a lot
